# Can we create notes using trigger on contact.?

Tags: visualforce, trigger, notes

I want to create notes (not attachment) using trigger on standard contact object.
I have 1 custom field called as notes__c, which i want to be reflected in notes once trigger gets fired.
Is it possible to create notes on every time contact is created and updated?
If yes then how can i achieve that?

Comment: Turning on [history tracking](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=tracking_field_history.htm&language=en_US) for that `notes__c` field isn't sufficient?

Comment: what will happen if i turn it on.

Comment: All changes to the field will be listed providing you have added the "History" related list to the layout.

Comment: Yes I got it. but it'll not show me the changes made to notes__c field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this trigger code :

```
trigger insertNote on Contact (after insert, after update){

    List<Note> noteList = new List<Note>();

    if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isInsert){

        for(Contact c : trigger.new){
            if(c.notes__c != null){
                Note newNote = new Note();
                newNote.Title = 'Custom Title';
                newNote.Body = c.notes__c;
                newNote.ParentId = c.Id;
                noteList.add(newNote);
            }
        }
    }

    if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isUpdate){
        for(Contact c : trigger.new){
            if(trigger.oldMap.get(c.id).notes__c != c.notes__c){
                Note newNote = new Note();
                newNote.Title = 'Custom Title';
                newNote.Body = c.notes__c;
                newNote.ParentId = c.Id;
                noteList.add(newNote);
            }
        }
    }


    if(noteList.size() > 0){
        insert noteList;
    }
}
```

Hope this may help.